# Accelerometer introduction? Code fix?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, accelerometer, move

The latest error:

[image]

I have recently been working on an app with a tutorial and come to a point where I would like to veer off from the tutorial. But I have next to no experience with SpriteKit so I would like some help working with the accelerometer to control something on the app.

The part where you control the space ship in the game is here:

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch: AnyObject in touches{

            let pointOfTouch = touch.locationInNode(self)
            let previousPointOfTouch = touch.previousLocationInNode(self)

            let amountDragged = pointOfTouch.x - previousPointOfTouch.x

            player.position.x  += amountDragged

            if player.position.x > CGRectGetMaxX(gameArea) - player.size.width / 2{

                player.position.x = CGRectGetMaxX(gameArea) - player.size.width / 2


            }

            if player.position.x < CGRectGetMinX(gameArea) + player.size.width / 2{
                player.position.x = CGRectGetMinX(gameArea) + player.size.width / 2
```

So could anyone either edit my code for me to use the accelerometer to control the ship or we could talk over Skype where I would like a little help. My Skype is RoobTheMan.

```
//  GameScene.swift
//  One Mission
//
//  Created by Robert Smith on 7/8/16.
//  Copyright (c) 2016 RobTheMan. All rights reserved.
//

import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate{


    let bulletSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("BulletSound.wav" , waitForCompletion: false)


    struct physicsCategories {
        static let None : UInt32 = 0
        static let Player : UInt32 = 0b1 // 1
        static let Bullet : UInt32 = 0b10 //2
        static let Enemy : UInt32 = 0b100 // 4

    }

    let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "playerShip")


    func random() -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)

    }
    func random(min min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
        return random() * (max - min) + min
    }      


    let gameArea: CGRect

    override init(size: CGSize) {

        let maxAspectRatio: CGFloat = 16.0/9.0
        let playableWidth = size.height / maxAspectRatio
        let margin = (size.width - playableWidth) / 2
        gameArea = CGRect(x: margin, y: 0 , width: playableWidth, height: size.height)


        super.init(size: size)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
        background.size = self.size
        background.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
        background.zPosition = 0
        self.addChild(background)


        player.setScale(1)
        player.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height * 0.2)
        player.zPosition = 2
        player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize:  player.size)
        player.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
        player.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = physicsCategories.Player
        player.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = physicsCategories.None
        player.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = physicsCategories.Enemy
        self.addChild(player)

        startNewLevel()

    }


    func startNewLevel(){


        let spawn = SKAction.runBlock(spawnEnemy)
        let waitToSpawn = SKAction.waitForDuration(1)
        let spawnSequence = SKAction.sequence([spawn, waitToSpawn])
        let spawnForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(spawnSequence)
        self.runAction(spawnForever)


    }


    func fireBullet() {

        let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet")
        bullet.setScale(0.8)
        bullet.position = player.position
        bullet.zPosition = 1
        bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bullet.size)
        bullet.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
        bullet.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = physicsCategories.Bullet
        bullet.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = physicsCategories.None
        bullet.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = physicsCategories.Enemy
        self.addChild(bullet)

        let moveBullet = SKAction.moveToY(self.size.height + bullet.size.height, duration: 1)
        let deleteBullet = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        let bulletSequence = SKAction.sequence([bulletSound, moveBullet, deleteBullet])
        bullet.runAction(bulletSequence)


    }


    func spawnEnemy(){

        let randomXStart = random(min: CGRectGetMinX(gameArea), max: CGRectGetMaxX(gameArea))
        let randomXEnd = random(min: CGRectGetMinX(gameArea), max: CGRectGetMaxX(gameArea))

        let startPoint = CGPoint(x: randomXStart, y: self.size.height * 1.2)
        let endPoint = CGPoint(x: randomXEnd, y: -self.size.height * 0.2)

        let enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemyShip")
        enemy.setScale(1)
        enemy.position = startPoint
        enemy.zPosition = 2
        enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: enemy.size)
        enemy.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
        enemy.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = physicsCategories.Enemy
        enemy.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = physicsCategories.None
        enemy.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = physicsCategories.Player | physicsCategories.Bullet
        self.addChild(enemy)

        let moveEnemy = SKAction.moveTo(endPoint, duration: 1.5)

        let deleteEnemy = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        let enemySequence = SKAction.sequence([moveEnemy, deleteEnemy])
        enemy.runAction(enemySequence)

        let dx = endPoint.x - startPoint.x
        let dy = endPoint.y - startPoint.y
        let amountToRotate = atan2(dy, dx)
        enemy.zRotation = amountToRotate

    }


    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        fireBullet()
    }


    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch: AnyObject in touches{

            let pointOfTouch = touch.locationInNode(self)
            let previousPointOfTouch = touch.previousLocationInNode(self)

            let amountDragged = pointOfTouch.x - previousPointOfTouch.x

            player.position.x  += amountDragged

            if player.position.x > CGRectGetMaxX(gameArea) - player.size.width / 2{

                player.position.x = CGRectGetMaxX(gameArea) - player.size.width / 2


            }

            if player.position.x < CGRectGetMinX(gameArea) + player.size.width / 2{
                player.position.x = CGRectGetMinX(gameArea) + player.size.width / 2
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry its pretty simple. First you have to do `import CoreMotion` at the top of the Swift file where the other imports occur - *outside* the class definition.

**Then do:**

```
//  GameScene.swift
//  One Mission
//
//  Created by Robert Smith on 7/8/16.
//  Copyright (c) 2016 RobTheMan. All rights reserved.
//

import SpriteKit
import CoreMotion
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate{


let bulletSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("BulletSound.wav" , waitForCompletion: false)
var motionTimer = NSTimer()
var motionManager: CMMotionManager = CMMotionManager()

struct physicsCategories {
    static let None : UInt32 = 0
    static let Player : UInt32 = 0b1 // 1
    static let Bullet : UInt32 = 0b10 //2
    static let Enemy : UInt32 = 0b100 // 4

}

let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "playerShip")


func random() -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)

}
func random(min min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
    return random() * (max - min) + min
}




let gameArea: CGRect

override init(size: CGSize) {

    let maxAspectRatio: CGFloat = 16.0/9.0
    let playableWidth = size.height / maxAspectRatio
    let margin = (size.width - playableWidth) / 2
    gameArea = CGRect(x: margin, y: 0 , width: playableWidth, height: size.height)


    super.init(size: size)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}




override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.01
    motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue(), withHandler:{
        deviceManager, error in
    })
    motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
    motionTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.001, target:self, selector: Selector("calculateMotion"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
    background.size = self.size
    background.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
    background.zPosition = 0
    self.addChild(background)


    player.setScale(1)
    player.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height * 0.2)
    player.zPosition = 2
    player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize:  player.size)
    player.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    player.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = physicsCategories.Player
    player.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = physicsCategories.None
    player.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = physicsCategories.Enemy
    self.addChild(player)

    startNewLevel()

}
func calculateMotion() {
    if let data = motionManager.accelerometerData {
        // you could do (you can change 2 to whatever you want - that makes it x times as fast/sensitive)
        player.position.x+=(CGFloat(2)*CGFloat(data.acceleration.x))
        if data.acceleration.x >= 0.8 || data.acceleration.x <= -0.8{
             //Make whatever you want to happen when there is acceleration happen here
        }
    }
}

func startNewLevel(){


    let spawn = SKAction.runBlock(spawnEnemy)
    let waitToSpawn = SKAction.waitForDuration(1)
    let spawnSequence = SKAction.sequence([spawn, waitToSpawn])
    let spawnForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(spawnSequence)
    self.runAction(spawnForever)


}


func fireBullet() {

    let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet")
    bullet.setScale(0.8)
    bullet.position = player.position
    bullet.zPosition = 1
    bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bullet.size)
    bullet.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    bullet.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = physicsCategories.Bullet
    bullet.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = physicsCategories.None
    bullet.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = physicsCategories.Enemy
    self.addChild(bullet)

    let moveBullet = SKAction.moveToY(self.size.height + bullet.size.height, duration: 1)
    let deleteBullet = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let bulletSequence = SKAction.sequence([bulletSound, moveBullet, deleteBullet])
    bullet.runAction(bulletSequence)


}


func spawnEnemy(){

    let randomXStart = random(min: CGRectGetMinX(gameArea), max: CGRectGetMaxX(gameArea))
    let randomXEnd = random(min: CGRectGetMinX(gameArea), max: CGRectGetMaxX(gameArea))

    let startPoint = CGPoint(x: randomXStart, y: self.size.height * 1.2)
    let endPoint = CGPoint(x: randomXEnd, y: -self.size.height * 0.2)

    let enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemyShip")
    enemy.setScale(1)
    enemy.position = startPoint
    enemy.zPosition = 2
    enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: enemy.size)
    enemy.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    enemy.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = physicsCategories.Enemy
    enemy.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = physicsCategories.None
    enemy.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = physicsCategories.Player | physicsCategories.Bullet
    self.addChild(enemy)

    let moveEnemy = SKAction.moveTo(endPoint, duration: 1.5)

    let deleteEnemy = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let enemySequence = SKAction.sequence([moveEnemy, deleteEnemy])
    enemy.runAction(enemySequence)

    let dx = endPoint.x - startPoint.x
    let dy = endPoint.y - startPoint.y
    let amountToRotate = atan2(dy, dx)
    enemy.zRotation = amountToRotate



}


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    fireBullet()
}


override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches{

        let pointOfTouch = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let previousPointOfTouch = touch.previousLocationInNode(self)

        let amountDragged = pointOfTouch.x - previousPointOfTouch.x

        player.position.x  += amountDragged

        if player.position.x > CGRectGetMaxX(gameArea) - player.size.width / 2{

            player.position.x = CGRectGetMaxX(gameArea) - player.size.width / 2


        }

        if player.position.x < CGRectGetMinX(gameArea) + player.size.width / 2{
            player.position.x = CGRectGetMinX(gameArea) + player.size.width / 2
        }

    }

}


}
```

You can change the *0.8* to something else later -> The lower the number the lower the acceleration threshold. You can also change *x* to *y* or *z* - just depends on which of your phones axes you want to detect acceleration for.

If you have any further questions or issues feel free to let me know **:)**

Comment: I have two questions, where would I put the code above after I imported CoreMotion and how would I link this to the left and right movement (I only need left and Right) of my SKSpriteNode?

Comment: @Rob I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve - I think you may want tilt sensitivity and not accelerometer. For steering a spaceship in a game, using an accelerometer would be very ungraceful - the user would have to keep moving their phone back and forth. But you would put the code above where your current code is now - inside the class declaration. Make sure that you get rid of one of the didMoveToView functions though - put the code that you have in your current project into the one in the code I pasted above. You can't have two of those function calls.

Comment: @Rob You could do something like player.position.x+=data.acceleration.x This would be inside the if let loop but outside the if loop checking if it's greater than 0.8

Comment: @Rob I've updated my answer with some of the relevant details mentioned above

Comment: I'm still very confused, could we please talk over Skype?

Comment: @Rob Sorry I don't have Skype. What specific part are you confused about?

Comment: @Rob If the my accelerometer comments were the problem: The accelerometer detects motion in the phone - not necessarily tilt but there is a way to detect tilt if you want that

Comment: I'm confused where your code connects to the controlling of my SKSpriteNode

Comment: @Rob where it says player.position.x+=data.acceleration.x Did you try putting the code in? What happened?

Comment: do i include my override function?

Comment: Copy and paste the code that is in the answer, then put the code in your current override function into the override function that you just put in, then delete the old override function but ONLY after you've put its code into the new one.

Comment: where can I send you a screenshot of all the errors I get?

Comment: When I said override I was referring to the function didMoveToView. Sorry about the confusion

Comment: And try CGFloat(data.acceleration.x)

Comment: Also change Timer to NSTimer

Comment: click still there, I've added another image

Comment: You declared didMoveToView twice. Move the original code in didMoveToView into the new one and then delete the old one. Also, comment out everything inside the OperationQueue (you don't need that anymore and also it won't work unless it's called globally inside a touchesDidMoved.

Comment: And change it to NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!

Comment: I'm very confused now, sorry but I don't have an extensive knowledge of code. So could you just edit your answer with the timer to include the fixes that you are making also with my code that I originally wrote?

Comment: Are you using swift 2 or swift 3?

Comment: i am using swift 2

Comment: @Rob Now just copy and paste my whole answer in, replacing the original code, and see what happens. Sorry this is taking so long ;)

Comment: @Rob Don't worry about it: try now :)

Comment: I'm sorry I was using Swift 3 code and I think that's whats causing some of the issues e.g. NSTimer was changed to the Swift specific Timer.

Comment: @Rob Change it from `player.position.x+=CGFloat(data.acceleration.x)` to `player.position.x+=(CGFloat(2)*CGFloat(data.acceleration.x))`. That will make it twice as fast. You can change it from two to whatever you want though. I'll update my answer too.

Comment: @Rob No, other than up vote my answer and mark it as correct, I don't really need anything ;) #keepcoding

Comment: @Rob Also check out me and my friend's platform at http://phonefiveme.com

Comment: @Rob Can you please upvote my answer and mark it as correct?